# Lookup names based on selection in other columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following table:

```
Name    Item 1    Item 2   Item 3    ... Item 28
Bob     Apple     Orange   kiwi          pair
John    Orange    pair     banana        peach
Dan     Peach     pair     kiwi          plumb
```

I need to list in a column names of all people that picked Kiwi. I have tried using a query but its giving me some really weird results and its not selecting every person for some reason.

```
=IFNA(QUERY(Wishlist!$A:$Z, "SELECT A WHERE B = """&A$2&""" OR C = """&A$2&""" OR D = """&A$2&""" OR E = """&A$2&""" OR F = """&A$2&""" OR G = """&A$2&""" OR H = """&A$2&""" OR I = """&A$2&""" OR J = """&A$2&""" OR K = """&A$2&""" OR L = """&A$2&""" OR M = """&A$2&""" OR N = """&A$2&""" OR O = """&A$2&""" OR P = """&A$2&""" OR Q = """&A$2&""" OR R = """&A$2&""" OR S = """&A$2&""" OR T = """&A$2&""" OR U = """&A$2&""" OR V = """&A$2&""" OR W = """&A$2&""" OR X = """&A$2&""" OR Y = """&A$2&""" OR Z = """&A$2&""" LABEL A ''"), "Nobody is Interested")
```

The result that I am getting is just one person is listed (the first one) and the rest don't show up. If I remove "Label A ''" part, then all the names in column A get listed as the label and still only first person shows up in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## solution 1:

Using the query formula as you had:

`=IFNA(query({B2:B,arrayformula(trim(transpose(query(transpose(Wishlist!A:Z),,rows(A:A)))))},"select Col1 where Col2 CONTAINS '"&A$2&"'"), "Nobody is Interested")`

Basically, instead of all of the rows you get, I joined them and then got the query to only 2 columns:

- `Col1` with the names
- `Col2` with values

Then I just look for if the second column contains kiwi inside.
[image]

## solution 2:

Counting how many in the rows:

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), countif(if(C2:F="kiwi", row(B2:B)), row(B2:B)),))`

You can see below what I did:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,MMULT(ROW(B2:B4)*(B2:F4=H2),ROW(A1:A5)^0)>0)
```

[image]

If you have more columns with items, then change second parameter of `MMULT` function accordingly - in my sample it is `ROW(A1:A5)^0` because range `B:F` has five columns. If you have, say, 28 columns, then there has to be `ROW(A1:A28)^0`.